# Prevent simplification/flattening/distribution of Simply

Tags: python, sympy

I am only really trying to use sympy to produce full equations using Latex. I don't need it to find me any answers necessarily. I have the following expression:

```
expr = Eq(S(DeltaX), ((V1 + V2) / 2) * DeltaT)
```

When it displays in latex it distributes the `2` denominator to both `V1` and `V2`.

```
(V1/2 + V2/2)
```

When I use `UnevaluatedExpr()` it converts it to a negative exponent:

```
(V1 + V2)*2**(-1)
```

And I haven't been able to use `evaluate=false` in any way it's happy with the syntax. Which is the only other possible solution I've found.

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour in SymPy is to distribute a Rational in a 2-arg Mul:

```
In [9]: (x + y) / 2
Out[9]: 
x   y
─ + ─
2   2
```

You can either control this using `evaluate=False` or the `distribute` context manager:

```
In [10]: Mul(Rational(1, 2), x + y, evaluate=False)
Out[10]: 
x + y
─────
  2 

In [13]: from sympy.core.parameters import distribute

In [14]: with distribute(False):
    ...:     e = (x + y) / 2
    ...: 

In [15]: e
Out[15]: 
x + y
─────
  2
```